# Xamarin Andorid Build Always Fails ("java.exe" exited with code 2)

Tags: c#, android, msbuild, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build a Xamarin.Android app, but the build always fails with `error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2`.  I've tried enabling ProGuard and multi-dex, deleting the bin and obj folders, updating all NuGet packages, switching to debug and release modes, and removing all unused references.  The error always points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets` on line 1965, but that does not help.  I've been struggling with this issue for days and I have no idea what to do next.  These are some SO questions that I've seen, but haven't helped:

- ["java.exe" exited with code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670261/java-exe-exited-with-code-2)
- ["java.exe" exited with code 2 Xamarin.Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004161/java-exe-exited-with-code-2-xamarin-android-project)
- [Java.exe exited with code 2 in android app build in VS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342885/java-exe-exited-with-code-2-in-android-app-built-in-vs-2015)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem

Comment: My issue was caused by the wrong JDK being used. VS2019 keeps auto-detecting the 'Eclipse Foundation JDK', when in fact it needed to use JDK 11 located at, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by creating a new project and copying the old project's code, resources, and packages to the new one.

Comment: I get that error in several projects. Some quite small.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to enable Multi-Dex in Android project.

1. Right click on Android project
2. Options
3. Android Build
4. General
5. Check: Enable Multi-Dex

Now Rebuild the project.

[image: Enable Multi-dex in Xamarin Android]

Answer (score 0):

Issue for me was `android-sdk` path containing "space". 
Run following command

```
mklink /J C:\andsdk "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"
```

and change the SDK path in `Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Sdk Location`

Enable MultiDex also if doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess and it's just a guess is this is related to a poorly constructed keystore or something amiss in Java, like an incorrect path. But I don't know what to do next and in the meantime my project is halted.